# What's the best way to create an anonymous static buffer inside a struct?

Tags: c

I have the following struct that is used primarily for dealing with dynamic malloc'ed arrays:

```c
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct {
    size_t cap;
    size_t len;
    uint8_t *data;
} bytearray;
```

I would like to create an macro `BYTEARRAY_STATIC_CREATE()` to create it on the stack. what should be the best approach to make this?

That's what I've tried

```c
#define BYTEARRAY_STATIC_CREATE(B, CAP) \
    B.len = 0;                      \
    B.cap = (CAP);                  \
    uint8_t __##B[CAP];             \
    B.data = __##B

int main()
{
    bytearray a;
    BYTEARRAY_STATIC_CREATE(a, 32);
}
```

Comment: How are they dynamic arrays if you're allocating on the stack?

Comment: @Chris there are situations in which i only need a fixed buffer size and I would like to use the already implemented functions to modify its content.

Comment: Are you in a situation where heap memory is severely constrained, or any performance hit for using `malloc` is critical? Otherwise this seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Chris well, its just so I don't have to worry about some failed return values of malloc

Comment: @Chris Using `malloc` wouldn't make a meaningful difference. There would still be same boilerplate code that the OP is asking about, just with an extra level of complication. The mention about dynamic memory in the question is only to clarify why `bytearray` is defined as it is.

Comment: @sloweax FYI, identifiers beginning with an underscore `_` are [reserved in C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/identifier#Reserved_identifiers). Strictly speaking, this code has UB.

Comment: For such a dynamic array, doing stack allocation is of limited value vs. a pure `malloc` approach. That said, I've done similar in the past. But, I'd add a `u32 opt;` field. With equates of: `OPT_ALLOC_STRUCT = 1u << 0 // struct allocated, OPT_ALLOC_DATA = 1u << 1 // data field allocated` Then, a free/destroy function will know whether it can do `free(ptr->data);` and `free(ptr);` or not. (e.g.) `if (ptr->opt & OPT_ALLOC_DATA) free(ptr->data); if (ptr->opt & OPT_ALLOC_STRUCT) free(ptr);` We know if we can increase `cap` and do `ptr->data = realloc(ptr->data,...);` or not

Comment: MS VC has `_alloca()` which uses the stack and is freed automatically. They have deprecated (but still support) that in favour of `_malloca()` which uses the stack or heap depending on the size, and always requires `_freea()` to be called after. Although in the case of a stack allocation IDK what happens if you don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically I see compound literals beeing used:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
struct bytearray {
    size_t cap;
    size_t len;
    uint8_t *data;
};
#define BYTEARRAY_STATIC_CREATE(size)  { \
      .len = size,  \
      .data = (uint8_t[100]){0} \
   }
struct bytearray hello = BYTEARRAY_STATIC_CREATE(100);
```

Comment: Compound literals are where I was going, too.

Comment: That's very neat, I also found that you could do something similar using `alloca`. Do you know which one is preferable?

Comment: @sloweax, in my experiance, `alloca()` is poorly regarded.  I see no reason even to consider it when the wanted capacity is a compile-time constant.  And if it isn't a compile-time constant then you wander into VLA territory, which is a whole other can of worms.

Comment: `Do you know which one is preferable?` Just because portability and standard compliance, compound literals would be preferred.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need `typedef` and pointer:

```
#define CREATEARRAY(name, size)         \
struct {                                \
    size_t cap;                         \
    size_t len;                         \
    unsigned char data[size];           \
}name = {.cap = 0, .len = size}


CREATEARRAY(hello, 32);    //static storage duration

int foo(void)
{
    CREATEARRAY(bar, 100);  //automatic stora
}
```

Same if you want to malloc. Use ***flexible*** array member

Comment: I like this, because it saves `sizeof(uint8_t*)` bytes for `uint8_t *data;`  pointer. Bottom line, if this approach is usable in OP context, depends on the actual usage of the type. Would be nice to give an example on how to pass the types to generic functions, and at best, convert the types to structure with flexible array member already in the macro.

Comment: This will work fine as long as the wanted `size` is not too large, and as long as they in fact don't need the structure to have a well-known type.  But if they want, say, to pass instances around to other functions then they might actually need a more general type, that is not specific to a particular array length.